# Mocking readFileSync with jest is working but only for get API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocking, jestjs

In app.js, there are get functions, which reads a data.json file from the filesystem.
in the post methods, it reads the json from the filesystem and writes it afterwards

I was able to mock the readFileSync function in jest, it works for all get calls, but when I call the post method, the mock doesnt work. No such file or directory appears. why does this happen?

app.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const dataFilePath = '../shoppinglist/data.json'
const baseUrl = '/api/v1/shoppingLists'
let client
let data
const fileSystem = require('fs')
app.disable('etag')
app.use(cors())

/**
 * Returns shoppinglist which matches the id
 *
 * @return shoppingList
 * @param {int} id of the shoppingList
 */
app.get(baseUrl +'/:id', (req, res) => {
    let id = parseInt(req.params.id)
    if(!isIdValid(id)){
       return res.status(404).send()
    }
    readUpdatedData()
    let filteredShoppingList = getShoppingListById(id)

    if(filteredShoppingList === undefined){
      return res.status(404).send()
    }else{
        //clone object
        let filteredData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
        filteredData.data = filteredShoppingList
        res.json(filteredData.data)
       return res.status(200).send()
    }
})

/**
 * Creates an object, calculates automatically the correct id.
 *
 * @param json object with shoppinglist, title required
 * @return 201 when title was given, 400 when no title or invalid data
 */
app.post(baseUrl, (req, res) => {
    const newData = req.body
    if(newData != null && !isEmpty(newData) && isRequiredFieldGiven(newData)){
        readUpdatedData()
        newData.id = getNewestId()
        data.data.push(newData)
        //updateData(data)
        console.log(data)
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        res.statusCode = 201
        res.json({"Location" : baseUrl + '/' + newData.id})
    }else{
        res.statusCode = 400
        res.send()
    }
})



    function readUpdatedData(){
        let rawData = fileSystem.readFileSync(dataFilePath)
        data = JSON.parse(rawData)
}
```

Tests in app.test.js

```
const request = require('supertest')
const shoppingListDataPath = ('../shoppinglist/data.json')
const baseUrl = '/api/v1/shoppingLists'
const appPath = '../src/app'
let mockedReadFile
let mockWriteFile

const {getSmsFormatedShoppingList} = require('../src/app')
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules()
    jest.clearAllMocks()
    let fs = require('fs')
    mockedReadFile = jest.spyOn(fs, 'readFileSync')
    mockWriteFile = jest.spyOn(fs, 'writeFileSync')

})

afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules()
    jest.clearAllMocks()
})

//this is working with mocks

describe('Get for all Lists with entries', () => {
    it('should return a list with 2 entries without items', async () => {

        mockReadFileCall({
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "filled shopping list",
                    "location": "lidl",
                    "targetDate": "22.03.1986",
                    "priority": 1,
                    "isFinished": false,
                    "items": [{"count": 1, "name": "vodka"}, {"count": 1, "name": "vodka"}
                    ]
                }, {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "filled shopping list2",
                    "location": "lidl2",
                    "targetDate": "22.03.1986",
                    "priority": 1,
                    "isFinished": false,
                    "items": [{"count": 1, "name": "vodka"}, {"count": 1, "name": "vodka"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        })


        const {app} = require(appPath)
        let res
        res = await request(app)
            .get(baseUrl)
        expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200)
        expect(res.body.data).toHaveLength(2)
        expect(res.body[0]).toEqual(expect.not.objectContaining({"items": ["vodka"]}))

    })
})


//this doesn't work

describe('create list entry', () => {
    it('should return 201', async () => {
        mockReadFileCall({
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "filled shopping list",
                    "location": "lidl",
                    "targetDate": "22.03.1986",
                    "priority": 1,
                    "isFinished": false,
                    "items": [{"count": 1, "name": "vodka"}, {"count": 1, "name": "vodka"}
                    ]
                }, {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "filled shopping list2",
                    "location": "lidl2",
                    "targetDate": "22.03.1986",
                    "priority": 1,
                    "isFinished": false,
                    "items": [{"count": 1, "name": "vodka"}, {"count": 1, "name": "vodka"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        })
        mockWriteFileCall()

        let {app} = require(appPath)
        const entry = {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "filled shopping list2",
            "location": "lidl2",
            "targetDate": "22.03.1986",
            "priority": 1,
            "isFinished": false,
            "items": [{"count": 1, "name": "vodka"}, {"count": 1, "name": "vodka"}
            ]
        }
        const res = await request(app)
            .post(baseUrl)
            .send(entry)
        expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(201)
        expect(res.body).toEqual({"Location": baseUrl + 1})
    })
})

function mockReadFileCall(testData){
   mockedReadFile.mockReturnValueOnce(JSON.stringify(testData))
}
```

EDIT
added not copied import

Comment: The code you're testing doesn't seem to import or use anything from `fs`, so it's unclear why you'd have to mock that at all.

Comment: changed  the post. missed the require statement while copy pasting

Comment: `mockReadFileCall` is not defined?

Comment: added the missing function call which defines mockReadFileCall

Comment: I've tried now with mockReturnValueOnce, this works just for the get calls, but error when post. When I change it to mockReturnValue, it doesn't work at all. Same for mockImplementation and mockImplementationOnce.

I guess there is something with the jest that it is only working when called once but I don't know why it doesnt work for multiple calls

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? What error do you get?

Comment: The error was, no such file or directory. I've solved it now with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63977366/how-to-mock-fs-readfilesync-with-jest/63977478?noredirect=1#comment113132214_63977478